# SQL Server: CTE, how to get last row number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a CTE like this:

```
;WITH Lastdt AS
(
    SELECT database_name, backup_finish_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY database_name ORDER BY backup_finish_date, database_name) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM bckHist
) 
SELECT database_name, backup_finish_date
FROM Lastdt
WHERE RowNumber = '7'
```

How can I get last row with highest number from the query (replace hardcoded 7)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need only last row (from your query) then it even simpler (for given case):

```
select database_name, max(backup_finish_date)
from bckHist
group by database_name
```

Comment: Yep, I was thinking this way too complicated!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easy...

```
;WITH Lastdt AS
(
    SELECT database_name, backup_finish_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY database_name ORDER BY backup_finish_date desc, database_name) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM bckHist
) 
SELECT database_name, backup_finish_date
FROM Lastdt
WHERE RowNumber = '1'
```

Comment: No, this does not produce the rihgt answer

Comment: that is probably because of quotes, try WHERE RowNumber = 1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
;WITH Lastdt AS
(
    SELECT database_name, backup_finish_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY database_name ORDER BY backup_finish_date, database_name) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM bckHist
) 
SELECT TOP 1 
   database_name, backup_finish_date
FROM Lastdt
ORDER BY RowNumber DESC
```

Basically order the `RowNumber` descending (largest first), and pick only the first one.

Comment: This retuns only one row, I last row (max rownumber) from every subset (based on database_name).

Comment: @atricapilla: yes, it returns only one row - that's what you asked for in your question....

Answer (score 0):

SELECT database_name, backup_finish_date FROM bckHist WHERE RowNumber = (SELECT MAX(RowNumber) FROM bckHist)